# position:fixed; is not working for Facelets Template

Tags: css, primefaces, facelets, jsf-2.2

I'm using primefaces 3.5. I want my template header to be in a fixed position such that it can't be scrolled while the content is scrolling. The xhtml is:

Template.xhtml

```
    <div id="top">
        <ui:insert name="top">Top</ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="center_content">
        <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom">
        <ui:insert name="bottom">Bottom</ui:insert>
    </div>
```

The css for the "top" is :top.css

`#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background: #036fab;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}`

I tried the above css in a html file .It  is working perfectly in .html files.
please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Have you considered using the Primefaces Layout component instead? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutFull.jsf